# Use styled components with data objects

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, react-props

**My question is**: Is it a way to style separate words in a data object?

example ->

```
export const dataObj = {
    id: 'solution',
    lightBg: false,
    lightText: true,
    lightTextDesc: true,
    topLine: '',
    topLineNO: '',
    headLine: 'I want to style "**This**" for example',
    headLineNO: '',
    buttonLabel: 'Read more',
    buttonLabelNO: 'Les mer',
    imgStart: true,
    img: require('../../../assets/img/zeiptisland.png'),
    alt: 'about img',
    dark: true,
    primary: true,
```

Let's say in the headline tag, I only want to style the word "This", like change color on only "This" for example.  Please someone tell me there is a way! :P

Below is the re-usable component that I use.

```
<Container lightBg={lightBg} id={id}>
                <ContainerWrapper>
                    <SolutionRow imgStart={imgStart}>
                        <Column1>
                            <TextWrapper>
                                <TopLine>
                                    {language === "no" ? topLineNO : topLine}  
                                </TopLine>
                                <Heading>
                                    {language === "no" ? headLineNO : headLine}
                                </Heading>
                                <Line></Line>
                                <Subtitle>
                                    {language === "no" ? descriptionNO : description}
                                </Subtitle>
                                
                                <BtnWrap>
                                    <Explore 
                                        smooth={true}
                                        duration={500}
                                        spy={true}
                                        exact="true"
                                        offset={-80}
                                        primary={primary ? 1 : 0}
                                        dark={dark ? 1 : 0}
                                        dark2={dark2 ? 1 : 0}
                                    >
                                        {language === "no" ? buttonLabelNO : buttonLabel}
                                    </Explore>
                                </BtnWrap>
                            </TextWrapper>
                        </Column1>
                        <Column2>
                            <ImgWrap>
                                <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
                            </ImgWrap>
                        </Column2>
                    </SolutionRow>
                </ContainerWrapper>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Content;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Seems like you're not using `dataObj` nor `headLine` somewhere. Can you show the code you actually render `headLine`?

Comment: in the compnent "Container"  inside the "Heading" tag,  i use a language state that will show either "headLineNo" or "headLine"  based on which language ive selected. Those two are the data which lays inside dataObj.. So as you may see i cant put a style directly into my component and pick out the word i want to separatly style.

Comment: No. you can not put style in your object and it magically render for you. You have to process the headLine first to get the right format (u can create a function to find all ***word*** and replace it with <span className="text-bold"></span>)

Comment: @VoQuocThang, okey, thanks for clearify that. But do you have an example on that function?